# A question inspired by Thomson's lamp and the Cantor Set

Tags: general-topology

If we have a line segment $L_1 = [0,1]$

let $L_2 = [a_2, b_2]$ where $a_2$ and $b_2$ are irrational and $a_2 \in L_1 \land b_2 \in L_1 \land a_2 < b_2$

let $L_3 = [x_3, y_3]$ where $x_3$ and $y_3$ are rational and $x_3 \in L_2 \land y_3 \in L_2 \land x_3 < y_3$

let $L_4 = [a_4, b_4]$ where $a_4$ and $b_4$ are irrational and $a_4 \in L_3 \land b_4 \in L_3 \land a_4 < b_4$

let $L_5 = [x_5, y_5]$ where $x_5$ and $y_5$ are rational and $x_5 \in L_4 \land y_5 \in L_4 \land x_5 < y_5$

$\dots$

We have $L_1 \supset L_2 \supset L_3 \supset L_4 \supset L_5 \dots$

If $\displaystyle \mathcal S = \bigcap_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty \ \mathcal L_n$

How many elements will set $\mathcal S$ have? Will that or those elements be rational , irrational or both or neither?

Comment: Is there a reason for alternating the letters from $a,b$ to $x,y$, other than confusing the reader?

Comment: a,b are irrational x,y are rational

Comment: What is Thomson's lamp? I might have heard of it but not by that name.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson%27s_lamp

Comment: Thank you for the reference, although I was disappointed to see it was just another case of a philosopher unable to  use logic.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your choice of numbers. Ultimately $\cal S$ is just the interval $[x,y]$ with $x=\lim x_n=\lim a_n$ and $y=\lim b_n=\lim y_n$.

If the lengths of your chosen intervals are shrinking, then $x=y$ and it will be a single point which may or may not be rational depending on the choice of your sequences. In fact, it's an easy exercise to show that it can be any point in $(0,1)$.

If the lengths are bounded above $0$, then $[x,y]$ is a non-degenerate interval and will contain both irrational numbers and rational numbers. As do all non-degenerate intervals.

Comment: To the O.P.:  For example we may have $\min L_n<1/3$ and $\max L_n>2/3 $ for all $n$, implying $S\supset [1/3,2/3].$  Or we may have $\lim_n\min L_n=1/2=\lim_n \max L_n  ,$ implying  $ S=\{1/2\}. $

Comment: If $S\supset [1/3,2/3]$ then there will be some $L_x = S$ and if there is such an $L_x$ then there will also be a $L_{x+1}$ where $[1/3,2/3]\supset L_{x+1}$ then the intersection will not be $ [1/3,2/3]$. The other problem is if $S=\{1/2\}$ then there will be some $L_n = [x_n,y_n] = \{ 1/2 \}$ then $x_n = y_n$ then the condition $x_n < y_n$ is not met.